# TFS Migration changetype mapping

Tags: tfs-migration, tfs-to-tfs-migration-tool

We're using the [TFS Integration Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5a8d1703-7987-4081-ba2f-9d0b68b0ed3e/) to migrate our source control history from a TFS 2008 instance to a TFS 2010 instance.  The TFS 2008 is an upgraded TFS 2005 instance, which causes a problem. In the discovery phase of the TFS Integration tool we get an error:

```
[2/23/2011 4:37:50 PM] TfsMigrationShell.exe Information: 0 : VersionControl: Starting analysis of TFS change 5267 
[2/23/2011 4:37:50 PM] TfsMigrationShell.exe Information: 0 : VersionControl: Unresolved conflict:  
[2/23/2011 4:37:50 PM]   Session: dd9ee183-8f17-42e4-acbb-a5bfb0c26d45 
[2/23/2011 4:37:50 PM]   Source: d95a9917-e8ec-46dd-92bb-86120d0b2a2a 
[2/23/2011 4:37:50 PM]   Message: Unrecognized conflict type 
[2/23/2011 4:37:50 PM]   Conflict Type: Unhandled ChangeType conflict type 
[2/23/2011 4:37:50 PM]   Conflict Type Reference Name: 361cd4e0-9955-42e0-a57c-ec3ade589e77 
[2/23/2011 4:37:50 PM]   Conflict Details: ChangeType 'Add, Edit, Encoding, Delete' is unrecognized.
```

This specific checkin is from the TFS 2005 instance; I assume that the "encoding" ChangeType was removed and is not recognized by the TFS 2010 instance.  I found only one related comment about this problem, on the [TFS Migration and Integration forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/tfsintegration/thread/56745986-a137-4b89-a090-756c25d87fa8), which seems to solve our problem:

> To resolve this conflict, you need to map this change combination to one that the migration tool understands.  In your situation, the file is added and deleted in the same changeset - I would suggest to map it to 'Delete'.

This wouldn't be a problem, except there's no documentation or examples on how to make this 
mapping; in fact the last comment on that thread asks that specific question.  I'm assuming that this change needs to take place in the XML of the TFS Integration configuration, but how??

Answer (score 1):

My understanding was that a TFS 2008 to TFS 2010 upgrade was not supposed to use the migration tool. Instead, you should be using the upgrade wizard that is part of the 2010 installation.

--EDIT--

I know you don't feel this is an upgrade, but since you are going from TFS 2008 to TFS 2010, *even though you are switching servers*, the Ranger's guidance calls that an upgrade.  From page 10 of the [Migration Guidance document](http://tfstotfsmigration.codeplex.com/releases/view/37382):

> There are two typical upgrade
>   scenarios:
>
> - A “move based” upgrade, which is recommended when moving to new
>     hardware. In this scenario you
>     typically copy the databases to a new
>     server and install TFS.
> - An “in-place” upgrade, which is the typical scenario when you remain on
>     the same hardware and wish to upgrade
>     to a later version of TFS.
>
> The standard TFS installation guide
>   covers both these scenarios in great
>   detail.

Comment: This is not an upgrade.. this is a migration from one server instance (TFS 2008) to another server instance (TFS 2010).. There is no upgrade happening in this place..

Answer (score 0):

As its a delete you can try exlcuding the path from migration.
In the migrate tool, add the path causing the error, then change path type to "Cloak" (or somthing like that I can't remember)
This is how I fixed the same error.